# Can someone please explain how to integrate open graph & Like button into wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to implement Open Graph and the “Like” button on my wordpress website.  I want to have the Like button positioned directly beneath a youtube video posted on one of my wordpress pages.

I have watched the facebook open graph video explaining the code to put onto your page, but it doesn’t explain how to do it in wordpress.  I have researched several wordpress plugins that implement open graph into your site, but they all seem to take data from the site itself and automatically implement it into the open graph data.  It also seems to me that using the “Like” button wordpress plugins, the like button is automatically placed either at the top or bottom of the page or in the sidebar.

Can anyone please help me understand exactly how to implement the open graph code into wordpress in a manner where I can control all the parameters of the code (image, url, site name, description, etc), and how to implement the Like button directly underneath of the video on my webpage?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if it's "for Wordpress" or not. Wordpress is a framework, not a language. Use the [Like Button Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) to generate the code you need for ANY Page - Wordpress or otherwise - and read up on the [Open Graph Protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) to give you an idea on how to write your <head> section.

Facebook's [Debugging Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) will also help you with any caching issues you may be experiencing, along with lots of extra information you might find useful in regards to your website.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I am not understanding is how to implement the code into specific wordpress pages.  Wordpress uses the same <head> information for all it's pages, and then I use a plugin to change specific meta data such as page title and description for the page (as far as seo purposes).  I don't know how to add the open graph code to the <head> section of a specific page in wordpress.  That is what has me confused.

Comment: Look in your /wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME_NAME/header.php file. That's where everything is being defined for your <head> tags. As far as your pages are concerned, barring theme-defined templates, the [Wordpress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) will tell you what each template name means, and what it's for.